# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'transition'). What does it mean?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I am created graphs with dynamic data from axios by chartjs library.
But when I refresh browser graphs at first nothing available, like this:

[image]

If I change dimensions for browser window - all graphs appears:

[image]

Error from concole:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'transition')
    at Chart.transition (Chart.js?473e:9865:1)
    at Chart.draw (Chart.js?473e:9827:1)
    at Chart.render (Chart.js?473e:9799:1)
    at Object.callback (Chart.js?473e:2208:1)
    at Object.advance (Chart.js?473e:3544:1)
    at Object.startDigest (Chart.js?473e:3517:1)
    at eval (Chart.js?473e:3506:1)
```

I don't have idea, why it can be so, and what to do.
It's look like firstly browser tried build graphs (but data didn't received yet).
During all calculation approximately 580ms.

[image]

This MainChart.vue for build charts:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas id="main-chart" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js'

export default {
  name: 'MainChart',
  props: ['chartData'],
  mounted() {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('main-chart');
    new Chart(ctx, this.chartData);
  }
}
</script>
```

This common page Analytics-test.vue.
I skipped all methods.

```
<template>
  <div> Прибыль/посещаемость <div class="small">
      <MainChart :chart-data="datacollection" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MainChart from '../MainChart.vue'
export default {
  components: { MainChart },
  
  data: () => ({
    flagStartDate: false,
    chartData: null,
    labels: [],
    datasets: {},
    draftData: null,
    data: [],
    datacollection: { type: 'line', },
    clubsId: ['5c3c5e12ba86198828baa4a7', '5c3c5e20ba86198828baa4c5', '60353d6edbb58a135bf41856', '61e9995d4ec0f29dc8447f81', '61e999fc4ec0f29dc844835e'],
      }),
  methods: {
...some a lot of code..},

 async mounted() {
    await this.loadIncomings(this.clubsId),
      await this.loadAvgIncomings(this.clubsId),
      await this.loadAvgPayments(this.clubsId),
      await this.loadAvgSchedule(this.clubsId),
      await this.loadTrainings(this.clubsId)

  },

</script>
```

There are 19 functions in methods, and I decided don't input here.

Comment: Please share the code where you used the Chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error seems similar to the one described in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5149 It sounds like it could be caused due to the fact that the chart is immediately loaded with data, but there are a couple of solutions in the comments on that issue.

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73335831/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-length-what-does-it-mean>.  I tried check this answer, but appear other mistake