# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length').What does it mean?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

There is one my question, that i try to solve. [Cannot read properties of null (reading 'transition'). What does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73323980/cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-transition-what-does-it-mean).
I checked option with integration mychart.update() from this question
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5149.
But when I tried start appears other error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
    at Object.acquireContext (Chart.js?473e:7756:1)
    at Chart.construct (Chart.js?473e:9324:1)
    at new Chart (Chart.js?473e:9311:1)
    at VueComponent.draw (Analytics-test.vue?b2a7:69:1)
    at VueComponent.loadTrainings (Analytics-test.vue?b2a7:444:1)
    at async VueComponent.mounted (Analytics-test.vue?b2a7:476:1)
```

Under you can see last code, that I tried to start.

```
<template>
  <div> Прибыль/посещаемость <div class="small">
      <canvas id="mychart" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js'
export default {
  data: () => ({
    flagStartDate: false,
    chartData: null,
    labels: [],
    dataset: {},
    draftData: null,
    data: [],
    datacollection: [],
    clubsId: ['5c3c5e12ba86198828baa4a7', '5c3c5e20ba86198828baa4c5', '60353d6edbb58a135bf41856', '61e9995d4ec0f29dc8447f81', '61e999fc4ec0f29dc844835e'],
    // clubsId: ['5c3c5e12ba86198828baa4a7', '61e999fc4ec0f29dc844835e'],
    // clubsId: ['61e999fc4ec0f29dc844835e'],
  }),
  methods: {

    draw() {
      if (this.mychart) {
        this.mychart.destroy();
      }
      const ctx = document.getElementById('main-chart');
      this.mychart = new Chart(ctx,
        {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: this.labels,
            datasets: this.datacollection
          },
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            elements: {
              line: {
                tension: 0 // disables bezier curves
              }
            },

            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                type: "time",
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: 'Time'
                },
                ticks: {
                  major: {
                    fontStyle: "bold",
                    fontColor: "#FF0000"
                  }
                }
              }],
              yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: this.labelY
                },
                ticks: {
                  min: 0, // it is for ignoring negative step.
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  stepSize: 1  // if i use this it always set it '1', which look very awkward if it have high value  e.g. '100'.
                }
              }]
            }
          }

        });
    },

    participantsCountClub(clubId) {
      switch (clubId) {
        case '5c3c5e12ba86198828baa4a7':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Фрунзенской", borderColor: "#3e95cd", fill: false }
        case '5c3c5e20ba86198828baa4c5':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Чернышевской", borderColor: "#8e5ea2", fill: false };
        case '60353d6edbb58a135bf41856':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Василеостровской", borderColor: "#e8c3b9", fill: false };
        case '61e9995d4ec0f29dc8447f81':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Московской", borderColor: "#3cba9f", fill: false };
        case '61e999fc4ec0f29dc844835e':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Лесной", borderColor: "#c45850", fill: false };
        default:
          return 'Неизвестный клуб';
      }
    },

    async loadTrainings(clubsId) {
      try {
        for (let clubId in clubsId) {
          clubId = clubsId[clubId]
          let dateFrom = '2021-06-01T00:00:00'
          let dateTo = '2022-08-01T23:59:59'
          let groupBy = 'month'
          await this.$store.dispatch('loadAvgSchedule', { clubId, dateFrom, dateTo, groupBy })
          this.draftData = this.$store.state.avgShedule
          if (this.labels.length === 0) {
            this.getDatesAvgIncome()
          }
          this.flagStartDate = true
          await this.getParticipantsCount(clubId)
          this.flagStartDate = false
        }
        this.draw()
        } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
    },

    async getParticipantsCount(clubId) {
      for (let item in this.draftData) {
        let positionDate = this.labels.indexOf(this.draftData[item].date.slice(0, 7))
        if (this.flagStartDate && positionDate > 0) {
          let zerroArray = await this.bindDataDates(positionDate)
          this.data = this.data.concat(zerroArray)
        }
        this.data.push(this.draftData[item].participantsCount)
        this.flagStartDate = false
      }
      this.dataset.data = this.data
      Object.assign(this.dataset, this.participantsCountClub(clubId))
      this.datacollection.push(this.dataset)
      console.log('this.datacollection', this.datacollection)
      this.data = []
      this.dataset = {}
    },

  },

  async mounted() {
    await this.loadTrainings(this.clubsId)
    
  },

  }
</script>

<style>
.small {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 150px auto;
}
</style>
```

And also I tried this option(with update()):

```
<template>
  <div> Прибыль/посещаемость <div class="small">
      <canvas id="mychart" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js'
export default {
  data: () => ({
    flagStartDate: false,
    chartData: null,
    labels: [],
    dataset: {},
    draftData: null,
    data: [],
    datacollection: [],
    clubsId: ['5c3c5e12ba86198828baa4a7', '5c3c5e20ba86198828baa4c5', '60353d6edbb58a135bf41856', '61e9995d4ec0f29dc8447f81', '61e999fc4ec0f29dc844835e'],
    // clubsId: ['5c3c5e12ba86198828baa4a7', '61e999fc4ec0f29dc844835e'],
    // clubsId: ['61e999fc4ec0f29dc844835e'],
  }),
  methods: {

    draw() {
      if (this.mychart) {
        this.mychart.destroy();
      }
      const ctx = document.getElementById('main-chart');
      this.mychart = new Chart(ctx,
        {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: this.labels,
            datasets: this.datacollection
          },
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            elements: {
              line: {
                tension: 0 // disables bezier curves
              }
            },

            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                type: "time",
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: 'Time'
                },
                ticks: {
                  major: {
                    fontStyle: "bold",
                    fontColor: "#FF0000"
                  }
                }
              }],
              yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: this.labelY
                },
                ticks: {
                  min: 0, // it is for ignoring negative step.
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  stepSize: 1  // if i use this it always set it '1', which look very awkward if it have high value  e.g. '100'.
                }
              }]
            }
          }

        });
    },

    participantsCountClub(clubId) {
      switch (clubId) {
        case '5c3c5e12ba86198828baa4a7':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Фрунзенской", borderColor: "#3e95cd", fill: false }
        case '5c3c5e20ba86198828baa4c5':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Чернышевской", borderColor: "#8e5ea2", fill: false };
        case '60353d6edbb58a135bf41856':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Василеостровской", borderColor: "#e8c3b9", fill: false };
        case '61e9995d4ec0f29dc8447f81':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Московской", borderColor: "#3cba9f", fill: false };
        case '61e999fc4ec0f29dc844835e':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Лесной", borderColor: "#c45850", fill: false };
        default:
          return 'Неизвестный клуб';
      }
    },

    async loadTrainings(clubsId) {
      try {
        for (let clubId in clubsId) {
          clubId = clubsId[clubId]
          let dateFrom = '2021-06-01T00:00:00'
          let dateTo = '2022-08-01T23:59:59'
          let groupBy = 'month'
          await this.$store.dispatch('loadAvgSchedule', { clubId, dateFrom, dateTo, groupBy })
          this.draftData = this.$store.state.avgShedule
          if (this.labels.length === 0) {
            this.getDatesAvgIncome()
          }
          this.flagStartDate = true
          await this.getParticipantsCount(clubId)
          this.flagStartDate = false
        }
        // Below I tried refresh charts after updates data
        this.mychart.update() 
        } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
    },

    async getParticipantsCount(clubId) {
      for (let item in this.draftData) {
        let positionDate = this.labels.indexOf(this.draftData[item].date.slice(0, 7))
        if (this.flagStartDate && positionDate > 0) {
          let zerroArray = await this.bindDataDates(positionDate)
          this.data = this.data.concat(zerroArray)
        }
        this.data.push(this.draftData[item].participantsCount)
        this.flagStartDate = false
      }
      this.dataset.data = this.data
      Object.assign(this.dataset, this.participantsCountClub(clubId))
      this.datacollection.push(this.dataset)
      console.log('this.datacollection', this.datacollection)
      this.data = []
      this.dataset = {}
    },

  },

  async mounted() {
    await this.loadTrainings(this.clubsId)
    this.draw()
  },

  }
</script>

<style>
.small {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 150px auto;
}
</style>
```

When I open string in debugger:
[image]

You can see that ref to this line:

[image]

If check last ref:

[image]

You can see this line:

[image]

Comment: `.length` in your code is attempting to read `this.labels.length`. So what is `this.labels` at the time of the error?

Comment: It means exactly that, that you can't read a property on null (null.length).

Comment: @user1599011 this.labels - it's a dates (for axis X). And this.label not empty in this moment (when chartjs try to build graph).  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kz2T.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvtv8.png

Comment: try logging it just before you check its length.

Comment: @user1599011 I did it :  i.stack.imgur.com/9kz2T.png i.stack.imgur.com/Gvtv8.png. console log appears before new Chart()

Comment: @user1599011 [![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSWWv.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAyMK.png  As you can see, when I logged data (labels and datacollection) - they not null

Comment: Okay, I missed the `item.length` in your screenshot (images aren't the best way to include code - they aren't searchable and links can break.) What is `item` just before you check its length?

Comment: @user1599011 May be item is ctx? Because, new Chart have two attrs : ctx and config.                                                                                     
 There peace of code from library chartjs:<https://codepen.io/spartachesko/pen/dymqrmJ?editors=0010> And this is last link to function where console tell me that item is null: <https://codepen.io/spartachesko/pen/LYdJadz?editors=0010>

Comment: Can you log it and see exactly what `item` is?

Comment: @user1599011 How to log it? I can't change code in other library. [![enter image description here][1]][1]
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7x9w.png

Comment: @user1599011 I can just log attrs before new Chart, but I did it

Comment: At some point you must be populating `item`? Maybe not directly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with template.
I forgot write correct id for canvas.
It must be so:

```
<canvas id="main-chart" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The property length is for Array, the error say it's not possible read of null (important that word "null") of legth, so the problem is that the const or var with that property become null for any reason.

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1] [![enter image description here][2]][2] [1]: i.stack.imgur.com/JSWWv.png [2]: i.stack.imgur.com/IAyMK.png    I logged data (labels and datacollection) - they not null